# Lua: Variable assignment via table

Tags: lua

currently I am trying to export and re-import some variables in LUA.
Imagine a table `AllGlobals`. The table contains all global variables used in my script, while `key` contains the variable name and `value` - surprise - contains the variable value.

What my script should do now is a reassignment of the variables. I started thinking about the following solution, which obviously isn't working:

```
1 function InsertGlobals()
2     for key,value in pairs(AllGlobals) do
3         key = value
4     end 
5 end
```

Well: Does anybody know a solution for assigning the value in line 3 to the variable name contained in key, not inserting it into the variable key itself?

Answer (score 1):

Solution to my own problem:

```
function InsertGlobals()
    for key,value in pairs(AllGlobals) do
        _G[key]=value
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You are only doing a shallow iteration - you don't transverse over tables in tables. For example, the table input wouldn't put something like examp.newfunc() into the _G as _G.examp.newfunc(). Also, it isn't wise to duplicate references of _G, package, and _ENV unless you really know what you are doing, meaning having a purpose.

```
function InsertGlobals(input)
    for key, value in pairs(input) do
        if(key ~= "_G" or key ~= "package" or key ~= "_ENV")then
            _G[key] = value
        end
    end
end
```

To fix the shallow iteration, all you need to do is a little recursion. I am sure you won't blow your stack with this, but if you leave _G, package, and _ENV then you definitely will.

```
function InsertGlobals(input)
    for key, value in pairs(input) do
        if(key ~= "_G" or key ~= "package" or key ~= "_ENV")then
            if(type(value) ~= "table")then
                _G[key] = value
            else
                InsertGlobals(value)
            end
        end
    end
end
```